# how does this scam work

Tags: scams

so, i know it's not totally about money, but you guy seems to alway know how they are making their money

since more than 6 mounth i got a lot of random friend request on steam from bots. usually i just ignore them, but yesterday  by mistake i accepted one of them and what they say to me was quite interesting. im pretty sure it's a human since he really respond to what i say. but he ask me to receive some skin that he would send to me  and then giving some back and that it can only be done by a foreign steam account.

i know the scam with real money, where they use your bank acount to launder money, and few mounth/year after the transaction the police come to see you.  but wih skin, is it the same thing, where they "launder" stolen skin/buyed with stolen card.  or is their another reason on why they would to that.

Comment: Agree with you, it's off-topic, but great thread on Steam scams here:  https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=756653421  Yours is perhaps a middleman scam if by foreign account they mean a 3rd party.

Comment: @HartCO: Many Steam items are region-locked, by "foreign" they're probably referring to the account's region.

Comment: @BenVoigt Never knew skins could be region locked, thought it was just at the game level. So maybe not a scam, but just someone needing a mule.

Comment: By “skin”, are you talking about apple peels or GUI styles?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically money laundering.
They are sending you dirty cash that you'll use to buy legit goods. This is how alot of game keys are originally obtained on the grey/black market.